How to help my tomato plants
I've got 2 tomato plants in pots that have been going for a couple of months now, but I've begun to notice some of the leaves beginning to discolour and fold inwards. We've had some pretty hot weather recently (23-30's Celsius) and they get a decent water every night.
Is this kind of colour indicative of a nutrient defficiency? I have some granular tomato fertiliser I added small amounts of (linked below) however that was when the first flower appeared. My main concern is whether this means I should add a bit more to the soil, they also get a liquid seasol feed every 2 weeks.
(https://www.richgro.com.au/product/plus-tomato-vegetable-fertiliser/)
Thanks


First thing I'd do (if I can) is soak the pots in a pot/barrel of water - ie immerse the whole pot in a larger pot and leave it for a minute or 2 until the air bubbles have gone.   It is possible that the plant is simply dehydrated.  (And, stupid as it sounds, watering the pot probably will not supply sufficient water to the roots, it drains away to quickly).     You can also somewhat tell if this is the issue if the pots feel lite when you lift them.   This brought my dying hydrangeas - which I also properly watered every day with a hosepipe - back to live in the space of hours.

Also, as an aside - if you are only watering once a day - and I expect with a pot that size it should be more often - you should consider watering in the morning.   The idea is to reduce the amount of time the leaves are wet and thus the risk of mold growing.   [ I don't always follow my advice though ]

Your fertilizer is high in nitrogen as tomatoes like. Also, tomatoes are heat lovers.

@davidgo I strive to always water anything in the morning. The plants can't absorb the water at night and I imagine it hinders whatever the roots are doing by flushing the air out.

@vorac not sure "flushing the air out" is a problem - I was taught - and it makes some sense, especially in Auckland - is that you want to avoid excess humidity which can cause mildew on the leaves etc.

Your tomatoes and the leaves are large, so there is nothing wrong with the soil or nutrients. Also, I see no pest symptoms on the plant. Therefore, the only possible thing here is heat or sun stress. Excessive sunlight or high temperatures can cause the leaves to curl as a protective response to reduce water loss. As far as I can see, this has been planted in a pot, so move it to a place with enough but not excessive sunlight.

Cool, thank you very much. I suspected it was some form of heat stress, as our weather has been swinging between cool and very hot this summer. Thank you for the suggestion!
